# Use requestAnimationFrame || $animate || directive || $timeout?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, performance, requestanimationframe

I have a directive in a table element that allows horizontal scroll. I have a fixed header which left position I update by binding the scroll event to the element that holds the directive(the table):

The link function of the directive updates the header position on the screen and brings a div over the table to block pointer-events.

It is obvious that this function forces some style recalc so my question is:

In the angular.js world what would be the best aproach. Should I use $animate, should I be setting the timeout the way I do it, would I avoid extended frames by requesting an animation frame(how is that done for this example?). Which way is best for performance?

Here is my current directive:

```
app.directive('checkScroll',  function() {
    return {
      // require: '^?listeditorController',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var timer = null;
            var screenBlock=  document.getElementsByClassName('blockEventsScreen')[0];
            // var lastLeft = 0;
            // requestAnimationFrame( scope.onScroll );
            elem.bind('scroll', function() {

            if(timer !== null) {
                //clear previous timer that turned off the during scroll tweaks
                clearTimeout(timer); 
                clearInterval(scope.interval);
                scope.interval = undefined;

                    //This sets the left style attribute of the table header container to the same value as the table body
                   var el=document.getElementsByClassName('fixedHeader')[0];

                   var newLeft = elem[0].getElementsByClassName('superResponsive')[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;


                screenBlock.style['transform'] = 'translateX(0px)';
                screenBlock.style['msTransform'] = 'translateX(0px)';
                screenBlock.style['MozTransform'] = 'translateX(0px)';
                screenBlock.style['WebkitTransform'] = 'translateX(0px)';
                screenBlock.style['OTransform'] = 'translateX(0px)';
                // var diff= Math.abs(newLeft - lastLeft );
                // if(diff>0){
                el.style['transform'] = 'translateX('+newLeft+'px)';
                el.style['msTransform'] = 'translateX('+newLeft+'px)';
                el.style['MozTransform'] = 'translateX('+newLeft+'px)';
                el.style['WebkitTransform'] = 'translateX('+newLeft+'px)';
                el.style['OTransform'] = 'translateX('+newLeft+'px)';
                // lastLeft=newLeft;        
                // scope.$apply(function(){
                //   $scope.headerLeft=newLeft+'px';
                // });
                    // requestAnimationFrame( scope.onScroll );
               // }
                }
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                      //remove screen  of table to enable pointer-events
                      screenBlock.style['transform'] = 'translateX(-10000px)';
                      screenBlock.style['msTransform'] = 'translateX(-10000px)';
                      screenBlock.style['MozTransform'] = 'translateX(-10000px)';
                      screenBlock.style['WebkitTransform'] = 'translateX(-10000px)';
                      screenBlock.style['OTransform'] = 'translateX(-10000px)';
                      //restart scaleheader after scrolling
                      scope.interval = setInterval( function(){scope.scaleHeader();}, 200);

                }, 200);




            });
        }
    }
});
```